# Why does my model only predict 0?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am using the River python package to work with streaming data.
After building a model I face an issue, every data value predicts as 0.
The data includes categorical and null values. I have used the pipeline and here is my code.

```
model = Pipeline(
    OneHotEncoder(sparse=True),
    PreviousImputer(),
    StandardScaler(),
    HoeffdingAdaptiveTreeClassifier())


y_true = []
for i in yy:
  y_true.append(i)
y_predict = []

metric = Accuracy()
for xi, yi in iter_pandas(XX, yy):
    model.learn_one(xi, yi)
    y_pred = model.predict_one(xi)
    y_predict.append(y_pred)
    metric.update(yi, y_pred)
    print(metric)
```

Here is the data I'm using:
https://www.kaggle.com/sohaibanwaar1203/adultscsv

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED

As per your code, you have utilized

- `River` python package.
- `OneHotEncoder`
- `PreviousImputer` for handling missing/null values
- `StandardScaler`
- `HoeffdingAdaptiveTreeClassifier` machine learning model.

In your code, you have utilized `learn_one` method which is stateless and actually does nothing, the next step you ideally need to do is to transform, `transform_one` will allow the features to be transformed. This is the most crucial data pre-processing step. Refer to links 1,2,3 in references that is for data pre-processing in `River` package

```
for xi, yi in iter_pandas(XX, yy):
    model.learn_one(xi, yi)
    model.transform_one(xi, yi)
    y_pred = model.predict_one(xi)
    y_predict.append(y_pred)
    metric.update(yi, y_pred)
    print(metric)
```

Without `transform_one` step, your input data is ideally sent to the model to be trained without making any actual changes to the input data. The main reason why your model has predicted incorrectly, as its been predicting with the null values, without actual data transformation.

**References:**

1. [OneHotEncoder](https://riverml.xyz/dev/api/preprocessing/OneHotEncoder/)
2. [PreviousImputer](https://riverml.xyz/dev/api/preprocessing/PreviousImputer/)
3. [StandardScaler](https://riverml.xyz/dev/api/preprocessing/StandardScaler/)
4. [HoeffdingAdaptiveTreeClassifier](https://riverml.xyz/dev/api/tree/HoeffdingAdaptiveTreeClassifier/)